# Linq to XML holding relationship

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML document with this structure:

```
<dipOrders>
    <interchangeInfo senderEdiCode="LSC58" senderEdiCodeQal="ZZ" receiverEdiCode="15274" receiverEdiCodeQal="ZZ" syntax="X12" syntaxId="X" syntaxVersion="003010"/>
    <order orderNumber="219299" orderDate="2012-12-05T00:00:00" validityDate="2012-12-05T00:00:00">
        <buyer name="LEAR MTO">
            <partyCode buyerCode="811567924"/>
        </buyer>
        <supplier name="BRIDGE OF WEIR LEATHER CO">
            <partyCode buyerCode="749630"/>
        </supplier>
        <orderConsignee name="LEAR MEXICAN SEATING CORP">
            <partyCode buyerCode="LSC59"/>
            <orderLine description="LEA DC 378 HERO 6RSB 5B8" orderNumber="246767" engineeringChangeNumber="N">
                <partyCode buyerCode="DC378105H6RSB5B8AA"/>
                <cumulativeQuantity date="2012-12-04T00:00:00" quantity="0"/>
                <orderQuantity quantity="0" commitmentLevel="Firm" timingQualifier="Weekly" shipDate="2012-12-05T00:00:00"/>
            </orderLine>
            <orderLine description="LEA DC 378 HERO 6RSB 5V0" orderNumber="246767" engineeringChangeNumber="N">
                <partyCode buyerCode="DC378105H6RSB5V0AA"/>
                <cumulativeQuantity date="2012-12-04T00:00:00" quantity="0"/>
                <orderQuantity quantity="0" commitmentLevel="Firm" timingQualifier="Weekly" shipDate="2012-12-05T00:00:00"/>
                <orderQuantity quantity="600" commitmentLevel="Firm" timingQualifier="Weekly" shipDate="2012-12-06T00:00:00"/>
            </orderLine>
```

This is how I access attributes of orderLine item:

```
List<int> orderNumbers = doc.Descendants("orderLine").Select(x => int)x.Attribute("orderNumber")).ToList();
List<string> descriptions = doc.Descendants("orderLine").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("description")).ToList();
List<string> buyerCodes = doc.Descendants("orderLine").Select(x => (string)x.Element("partyCode").Attribute("buyerCode")).ToList();
```

However, orderLine can have different number of orderQuantity nodes. How can I address it in the Linq statement to get the appropriate relationship between orderLine and orderQuantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get orderQuantity element by using this

```
var data = doc.Descendants("orderLine").
               Descendants("orderQuantity")
             .Select(x =>   new {paernt = x.Parent, x}).ToList();
```

also do like this

```
var data = doc.Descendants("orderLine").
               Descendants("orderQuantity")
             .Select(x =>   new {OrderNumber= (int) x.Parent.Attribute("orderNumber"), 
                                                                      x}).ToList();
```

Comment: But this way I get all "quantities" without knowing which orderLine do they belong to

Comment: @Bartosz - above updates will give you child and parent both element i.e. orderline and order qunatity...

Comment: But this gives me general data object, how can I now dig through it to get the values for different attributes

Comment: @Bartosz - for that i think you need to loop through or  in select new will be chaged like this new {paerntOrdernumber = x.Parent.Attribute("orderNumber"), x}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SelectMany` like in next example

```
var r = doc.Descendants("orderLine")
           .SelectMany(node => node.Elements("orderQuantity")
                                   .Select(el => new {OrderNumber = (int)node.Attribute("orderNumber"), Quantity = (int)el.Attribute("quantity")}));
```

Now you have a sequence of anonymous objects indicating order number and corresponding quantity, like:

```
246767 0 
246767 600
```

Comment: But how can I preserve the relationship, knowing which quantity belongs to which orderLine